# Calling Emacs from Java file

Tags: java, emacs

For vhdl beautifier, I am using Emacs and in Linux I am using the command in terminal:

```
emacs --batch --visit=FILENAME.vhd --funcall=vhdl-beautify-buffer --funcall=save-buffer
```

And this working fine, however when trying to call this command within a java file as below not working! :

```
String command = "emacs --batch --visit=FILENAME.vhd --funcall=vhdl-beautify-buffer --funcall=save-buffer";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

what can be causes for that?

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: I am getting no response, i got empty output when using BufferedReader
normally when running the command in the terminal i got 
VHDL Mode 3.33.6.                                                                                                                                                                                  
Indenting...done  
...

Comment: What happens if you run the command in the terminal but redirect the output to a file?

Comment: I think you need to write the full path of `emacs`, maybe you should try to see the value of $PATH when you are running the command in the jvm

Comment: i have tested now to call in java 
command = "emacs --version"; 
and this is working fine so i think the path of emacs is ok or ?

Comment: maybe the `--visit=FILENAME.vhd` isn't correct, the path of the filename is not correct